# How to run the eBPF examples from `[linux_source_root]/samples/bpf`?

Tags: linux, ebpf

I'm new to eBPf, I saw [some examples in the kernel sources](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.9/source/samples/bpf), I wonder how to run these examples?

What I know is that eBPF programs are running in kernel and user applications are running in userspace. I learned from toturial that eBPF programs can be written in python, eg:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from bcc import BPF

prog = """
int hello(void *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("Hello world\\n");
    return 0;
}
"""

b = BPF(text=prog)

# attach the program to an event
clone = b.get_syscall_fnname("clone")
b.attach_kprobe(event=clone, fn_name="hello")
b.trace_print()
```

I can directly use the command `./helloworld.py` to make it run.

But the files in [linux source file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.9/source/samples/bpf/sockex1_kern.c) are hard for me to get them run like the python above.

Comment: Your BCC program is not written in Python but in C. For the kernel samples, did you look at `samples/bpf/README.rst`? It provides all the details for building the examples. Once built, you can simply run the executables or scripts, depending on the examples. They are less oriented towards discovering eBPF, and more about understanding the eBPF features in the kernel, though.

Comment: yes, I have seen the readme file, but I cannot understand how to run these examples.